# Read Access to all files for sharing purposes

Tags: java, android, permissions, sd-card, android-permissions

I'm writing a simple app that is available in the share menu e.g. in the gallery for sending images to my computer. To do this I have to read the bytes of the shared file:

```
File f = new File(filename);
int size = (int) f.length();
byte bytes[] = new byte[size];
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
fis.read(bytes, 0, size);
```

But I always get the following error, no matter where the shared file is saved:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: myfilename: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

How can I archieve access to the files shared to my app?

I have the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in my manifest.

Comment: What is the the value of `filename`? From the error, it appears as though you have `filename` set to a value of `"myfilename"`, and there is no such file.

Comment: The value is a real file, I retrieve it directly from the URI from the SEND intent

Comment: "I retrieve it directly from the URI from the SEND intent" -- since [a `Uri` is not necessarily a file](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html), that is not going to work reliably. [Use the `Uri` properly](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html), by calling `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`.

Comment: By "retrieve" I meant "converting" it into a path... I checked it, the path is correct

Comment: Are you using Android M? You should request permissions at runtime https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: You cannot reliably convert a `Uri` into a filesystem path. A `Uri` does not have to point to a file. [Use the `Uri` properly](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html), by calling `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`. For the subset of cases where the `Uri` actually happens to point to a file on the external storage portion of the filesystem, make sure that [you are requesting `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` properly](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/08/31/hey-where-did-my-permission-go.html).

Comment: Requesting permission did it for me, thanks